# Using bandwidth allocation effectively in a shared connection

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I have a shared internet connection. So I use Netlimiter. I installed it on my desktop and it works perfectly. My doubt is what will happen if I install it on all the systems and allocate bandwidth. Is there anything available to make a system master in the shared connection. So, that all will follow the rule.

Comment: Have you looked in QoS(Quality of Service) on your router? You can specify certain mac addresses, ports on the router, and/or ip addresses to take priority over others.

Comment: QoS won't help him. He's concerned with allocating the inbound bandwidth.